# I cannot call jaspert report jrxml from java application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to call my report and show it but it did not work!!!

this is the code:

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package Frames;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Ma3d Sa3eed
 */
public class ReportViewer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    java.awt.Container c;

    public ReportViewer(String rptPath, HashMap parameter) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            java.sql.Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ora10g", "employees", "manager");
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rptPath, parameter, con);
            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
            c = getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
            c.add(viewer);
            show();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?, error message?

Answer (score 0):

I would load a JasperReport object and pass the fill manager that and not just a path like so with your rptPath (assuming it's the full file path of your jasper report):

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(rptPath);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameter, con);
```

Then pass that to the JFrame you want to show the report in.

Comment: Thanks for your help, brother.
I am still have an exception, this is my call section:
    
    public static void main(String...args){
        new ReportViewer("C:\\Users\\Ma3d Sa3eed\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Employees\\src\\Reports\\report1.jrxml", null);
    }
}

THIS IS THE StackTrace:
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:68)

Comment: The error is telling you that you are missing a library used by the JRLoader.  I believe it's the commons logging jar from Apache found here:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming your abc.jrxml is inside a folder xyz :

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/xyz/abc.jrxml");
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
JasperPrint finalReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameter, con);
```

Comment: yes, I have my jrxml file in folder calll Reports and I have changed it to:
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/report1.jrxml");

but I am still having an exception called:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
In the Line:
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have apache commons jar in your project.?